# Laravel route: how dynamiccally use routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I have two same URLs. How dynamically redirect to the right route?

I used ->where(), but I understand, it is just to validate variable, not filter route entering.

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/{model}/{method}/{id?}', [CrudController::class, 'index'])
   ->defaults('id', '')
   ->defaults('config', $config)
   ->where('model', 'Task');

 
 //Hide headers, for users
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/{model}/{method}/{id?}', [CrudController::class, 'index'])
   ->defaults('id', '')
   ->defaults('config', $config_user)
   ->where('model', 'User');
```

Comment: This is not possible as both have the same pattern style. Add a distinguisher like `task/{model}/{method}/{id?}` and `user/{model}/{method}/{id?}`. This is also useful to avoid confusion with future routes.

Comment: Why are you working against the framework?

Comment: You mean, why i don't use static part for {model}? Because, on final code, that would mean 20 blocks of copy / paste.

Answer (score -1):

I solved problem dirty way(Laravel 8.0), hope in future versions, Laravel will offer route filtering, by variable.

```
 $model = request()->segment(1);
 
 if (in_array($model, $config['allow_models']))       
   Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/{model}/{method}/{id?}', [CrudController::class, 'index'])
     ->defaults('id', '')
     ->defaults('config', $config);

 else if (in_array($model, $config_user['allow_models']))
   //Hide headers, for users
   Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/{model}/{method}/{id?}', [CrudController::class, 'index'])
     ->defaults('id', '')
     ->defaults('config', $config_user);
```